# What is the volume of the Parallelepiped made using vectors $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b} ,\overrightarrow{c}$?

Tags: vectors

I am studying for my exam next week and stumbled upon a question I can't answer.

It is given that $\overrightarrow{d}= (2\overrightarrow{a}+3\overrightarrow{b}+\overrightarrow{c}) \times (5\overrightarrow{a}+3\overrightarrow{b}+2\overrightarrow{c})  $
and that $ \overrightarrow{a},\overrightarrow{b},\overrightarrow{c} \in \mathbb{R}^3 $.
Also given that $\overrightarrow{a} \cdot \overrightarrow{d}=12$.

What is the volume of the Parallelepiped made using vectors $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b} ,\overrightarrow{c}$ ? The answer is 4.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Expand using linearity and antisimmetry of vector product:

$(2a+3b+c)\times(5a+3b+2c)=$

$=6 a\times b+4a\times c+15 b\times a+6b\times c+10c\times a+3c\times b$

$=-9a\times b-6a\times c+3b\times c$

Now take scalar product with a . Take advantage of the cyclic property of the triple scalar product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product:

$12=3(b\times c)\cdot a$

so that, calling $V$ the required volume :

$12=3V \rightarrow V=4$